# export button create outside Highchart using Angular and Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, highcharts, ionic4, ionic5

I am created highchart and I try to put the export button outside the chart. but I didn't get in the ionic angular framework.

I tried to export a chart in SVG.
I am gone through this link: http://jsfiddle.net/tLfeaL7y/
In this exporting as javascript:
Code: Select all

```
 $('#export_JPG').click(function() {
    chart.exportChartLocal({
      type: 'image/jpeg'
    });
  });
```

***If there any way to export in IONIC 5 and Angular.***

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo shows how to create a custom button which triggers the chart downloading on click in the Angular environment.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-js9nk

```
  test = () => {
    console.log(this.Highcharts.charts)
    this.Highcharts.charts[0].exportChart({
      type: 'image/jpeg',
      filename: "line-chart"
    });
  }
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#exportChart